Why did this question regarding ARINC 429 behavior get closed as off topic
When looking through the ARINC 429 tag questions to see if I missed one, I noticed this question got closed as off topic.
Arinc 429: how to detect the data frame start?
I'm curious to see why users on ASE might view questions regarding ARINC 429 as off topic for ASE.
There have been plenty of other questions with the ARINC 429 tag that were not closed as off topic.

You're right, this does seem a little inconsistent.
Stack Exchange works on a system of reputation with actions performed on the site giving access to tools which give users certain privileges. At 3,000 rep users gain the vote to close privilege.
In this case, 3 users' voted to close the question as off topic.
If I we're to hazard a guess, it is because to me the question looked more like a programming question, perhaps more suited to Stack Overflow, than a question about the aviation aspects of ARINC 429. This doesn't necessary mean other similar questions were also closed, just that this particular one got enough votes to close it.
The good news is, that 3 reopen votes will reverse that decision, and often a post like this garners enough attention in these edge cases to make that happen!
